# How to move files from EC2 to S3 using AWS CLI ? The files should be deleted from EC2 once transferred to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I setup an SFTP server on Debian EC2 instance. I setup a cron job using `aws s3 sync <source dir on EC2> <destination S3 bucket>`. I issue is that my EC2 will get full as uploads come in.

Once a file is uploaded to EC2 instance, I want the file to moved to S3 bucket. `sync` command just copies it and doesn't delete from source. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: `aws s3 mv filename.ext s3://example-bucket/filename.ext`

Comment: Do I have to specify the filename with `aws s3 mv`? Can I just specify the directory and any files uploaded to the directory are automatically moved by cron?

Comment: Use [`--recursive`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/mv.html) to upload an entire folder and delete it upon successful upload.

Comment: I want to move the CONTENTS of the folder and not delete the folder itself. Does `aws s3 mv --recursive` do that or it moves the folder itself with contents?

Comment: Then call mv on the contents, however you define that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `aws s3 mv` command actually performs a `CopyObject()` and a `Delete`.

To move a whole directory, use:

```
aws s3 mv --recursive localdir s3://bucket-name/
```

If you want to move the 'contents' of the directory, try:

```
aws s3 mv --recursive localdir s3://bucket-name/ --exclude "*" --include "localdir/*"
```

See: [mv — AWS Command Reference](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/mv.html)

Comment: Can you explain what `--exclude "*"` is doing? I understand the include argument.

Comment: See the linked documentation. Exclude is saying "don't copy any files", and then Include is saying "copy all files in the given directory".